# Accuracy : Arima Vs Feed-forward neural networks

Tags: neural-networks, arima, accuracy, model-comparison

I try to choose the best model between the `Arima` model and the `Feed-forward neural networks`. 
The script runs well and I use the `accuracy` function to compare the to algoritm.
I use the `RMSE`to chouse the best model, is enough or I have to compare other parametres?
I'd like to precise that the data set is equal and the numbers are normalization between 0 and 1.

Below the results of the two algorithms:

**ARIMA MODEL**

```
                  ME             RMSE         MAE    MPE  MAPE    MASE        ACF1
Training set  -2.284042e-06 0.005978466 0.003094135 -Inf  Inf   1.006384  -0.0004549235
```

**FEED FORWARD NEURAL NETWORKS MODEL**

```
                  ME           RMSE         MAE    MPE   MAPE     MASE        ACF1
Training set -7.196957e-06 0.00571893 0.003075926 -Inf   Inf    1.000462   0.00461708
```

In this case I chouse the Feed Forward Neural Network because the RMSE is lower respect the Arima, but my question are:

is enouth lower the RMSE?

I have to do another type of test and consider also it?

Thank in advance for any type of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to make sure that the difference in losses is statistically significant is to check the distributions of such metrics in the test dataset (not training as I see you are doing as long as you want the model to generalize to unseen data). You can check p-values and confidence intervals.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: (1) Neural networks are not estimated by maximum likelihood. (2) It is difficult to obtain an estimate of their degrees of freedom. Because of (1), LR test is not a good choice. Because of (1) and (2), AIC is not a good choice.